# Php putting amount of characters after string

Tags: php

I'm a front end developer but I'm learning php so I can do basic back end stuff. My code seems to be putting the amount of characters after the echoed string.

```
<?php
  $openFile = fopen("file.txt","w");
  $name = "Chris";
  fwrite($openFile,$name);
  fclose($openFile);
  $openFile = fopen("file.txt","r");
  echo readfile("file.txt");
  fclose($openFile);
?>
```

This is what I get for posting here. -2.

Live preview: http://icodewebsitesandineedatestingserver.netai.net/

Comment: Post your code here instead of posting it in somewhere else and sharing the link.

Comment: Show us your code plus an expected output and actual output so we can help you

Comment: Every time I try that stackoverflow wants me to format it and when I do it correctly it still wont let me paste the code.

Comment: When you past the code in, select it and hit CTRL-K to indent it in automatically as code.

Comment: I tried that. Also, The expected output is : Chris not Chris5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to read the contents of the file?

PHP doc on readfile:
`Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.`

5 is the number of bytes read.

You can use `file_get_contents`:

```
<?php
  $openFile = fopen("file.txt","w");
  $name = "Chris";
  fwrite($openFile,$name);
  fclose($openFile);
  echo file_get_contents("file.txt");
?>
```

Comment: Finally! Someone around here that is actually helpful!